# Multiple 'when' conditions on Joi validation

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

Context

- *node version*: 6.11.3
- *joi version*: 10.0.6
- *environment* (node, browser): browser
- *used with* (hapi, standalone, ...): standalone
- *any other relevant information*: if I comment out one condition at a time, both work on their own.

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I've got a radio button group that needs a ***two part validation schema*** with both parts conditionally required based off of each other's values. If a user selects the last option 'other', an input field will appear for them to manually enter another number

The first validation should, require there be a selection of the first three ***if the fourth option is not selected.***

The second validation should be, if the selection value is 'other', ignore the input mask and require the input be filled with a 10 digit phone number.

[image: screen shot 2017-12-11 at 8 58 19 pm]

```
const cardContactSchema = {
  selectedCardNumber: Joi.string()
    .label('Phone Number')
    .when('otherPreferredCardNumber', {
      is: Joi.string().empty(''),
      then: Joi.string().required(),
    }),
  otherPreferredCardNumber: Joi.string()
    .label('Phone Number')
    .when('selectedCardNumber', {
      is: 'other',
      then: Joi.string()
        .replace(/\D/g, '')
        .length(10)
        .required()
        .options({
          language: {
            string: {
              length: 'length must be {{limit}} digits',
            },
          },
        }),
      otherwise: Joi.string().optional(),
    }),
};
```

**Current result:**

`Error: item added into group otherPreferredCardNumber created a dependencies error(otherPreferredCardNumber)`

**What I expect:**
The first validation should, require there be a selection of the first three ***if the fourth option is not selected.***

The second validation should be, if the selection value is 'other', ignore the input mask and require the input be filled with a 10 digit phone number.